# Facebook Graph API Issue An unexpected error has occurred

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am making the following call to facebook graph API to get data stream from one of my facebook group(closed group).

https://graph.facebook.com/GROUP-ID/feed?access_token=MY-TOKEN

This was working for the past one year. Yesterday it started giving the following error

{
   "error": {
      "message": "An unexpected error has occurred. Please retry your request later.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 2
   }
}

I tried using the access token of a different facebook user and it is working fine.

But when I tried using my token it is throwing error.

Then I tried adding limit to the API call like this

https://graph.facebook.com/GROUP-ID/feed?access_token=MY-TOKEN&limit=3

This worked fine. When I increased the limit beyond 3 the same error occurred. Any Idea?

Using the same access token I am able to access data from my other groups. So I think the token is valid. I am really confused. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Getting the same behaviour now. Quite odd. May have something to do with the size of data being sent back ?